# How to get the custom dimension data passed through js, from my google analytics account?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have added google analytics Script along with my asp.net website, I was able to get the active users and location, etc. But I cannot get the report that consists of the custom dimensions I have passed. The javascript code which I have used is below.​

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxx-x"></script>
<script>  
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', {
     'custom_map': {
       'dimension1': 'district_state',
       'dimension2': 'district_name',
       'dimension3': 'user_type',
       'dimension4': 'district_school_name'
     }
  });


gtag('event', 'data', {

    'district_state': $('#ctl00_hdnState').val(),
    'district_name': $('#ctl00_hdnDistrict').val(),
    'district_school_name':$('#ctl00_hdnProvider').val(),
    'user_type': $('#ctl00_HdnRole').val()
});
```

​

How can I get the report consist of district_state,district_name,district_school_name and user_type?

Answer (score 0):

you can use your custom dimensions as secondary dimensions[image] in your standard analytics reports or build a custom report containing your dimensions: